# Error while installing the .net windowservice :The name is already in use as either a server or service name

Tags: .net

I build a new window service on my machine and copy the whole proj to the server and try to install the window service on server machine .
i dont install the service in my machine...

i get the following error :

An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The name is already in use as either a se
vice name or a service display name

but if i run install in my local machine it works.

is it because the project i have built in my machine and that service somehow get registered to my IP.

Serivce name also i have kept it is unique.

any suggestions ppl?

Answer (score 2):

Your unique service name is in use as a service name or as a display name on the the server machine. It is not in use on your local machine, so it works.

Ensure that the service that already uses your service name is an older version of your service, the Uninstall the old version of the service from the server first, before attempting to install your newer version.

If the service that uses your service name is not an older version of your service, then pick a better name, one that has a lower proobability of being already in use.